# How does the Pandas deal with the situation when a column with type "object" is compared with an integer?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison-operators

My question is about the rule that pandas uses to compare a column with type "object" with an integer. Here is my code:

```
In [334]: df
Out[334]: 
     c1    c2        c3  c4
id1   1    li -0.367860   5
id2   2  zhao -0.596926   5
id3   3   sun  0.493806   5
id4   4  wang -0.311407   5
id5   5  wang  0.253646   5

In [335]: df < 2
Out[335]: 
        c1    c2    c3     c4
id1   True  True  True  False
id2  False  True  True  False
id3  False  True  True  False
id4  False  True  True  False
id5  False  True  True  False

In [336]: df.dtypes
Out[336]: 
c1      int64
c2     object
c3    float64
c4      int64
dtype: object
```

Why does the "c2" column get `True` for all?

P.S. I also tried:

```
In [333]: np.less(np.array(["s","b"]),2)
Out[333]: NotImplemented
```

Comment: Funnily enough, both `df > 2` and `df < 2` yield all `True`

Comment: I tried overriding the __le__ (less than) and __ge__ (greater than) routine of a class to always return False, and df > 2 still returns True. My guess is that pandas overrides every object to return True on comparison for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For DataFrames, comparison with a scalar always returns a DataFrame having all Boolean columns.

I don't think it's documented anywhere officially, but there's a comment in the source code (see below) confirming the intended behaviour:

> [for] straight boolean comparisons [between a DataFrame and a scalar] we want to allow all columns (regardless of dtype to pass thru) See #4537 for discussion.

In practice, this means that all comparisons for every column must return either `True` or `False`. Any invalid comparison (such as `'li' < 2`) should default to one of these Boolean values.

Put simply, the pandas developers decided that it should default to `True`.

There's some discussion of this behaviour in [#4537](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4537) and some argument to use `False` instead, or restrict the comparison to only columns with compatible types, but the ticket was closed and no code was changed.

If you're interested, you can see where the default value is used for invalid comparisons in an internal method found in [ops.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L1811-L1816):

```
def _comp_method_FRAME(cls, func, special):
    str_rep = _get_opstr(func, cls)
    op_name = _get_op_name(func, special)

    @Appender('Wrapper for comparison method {name}'.format(name=op_name))
    def f(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ABCDataFrame):
            # Another DataFrame
            if not self._indexed_same(other):
                raise ValueError('Can only compare identically-labeled '
                                 'DataFrame objects')
            return self._compare_frame(other, func, str_rep)

        elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries):
            return _combine_series_frame(self, other, func,
                                         fill_value=None, axis=None,
                                         level=None, try_cast=False)
        else:

            # straight boolean comparisons we want to allow all columns
            # (regardless of dtype to pass thru) See #4537 for discussion.
            res = self._combine_const(other, func,
                                      errors='ignore',
                                      try_cast=False)
            return res.fillna(True).astype(bool)

    f.__name__ = op_name
    return f
```

The `else` block is the one we're interested in for the scalar case.

Note the `errors='ignore'` argument, meaning an invalid comparison will return `NaN` (instead of raising an error). The `res.fillna(True)` fills these failed comparisons with `True`.

Comment: Seems like a weird design decision to me to not keep the NaNs. Especially as the library liberally uses NaNs elsewhere when there's no sensible value for a field.